# Duplicating an excel column from a found cell with Applescript

Tags: excel, applescript

I want to be able to duplicate an entire column from a found cell.

I have been able to create some code to find the cell. Now, I need to be able to select the entire column where the cell has been found and then duplicate it to the column AA in order to start my macro.

The column "other_values" will always be present in the report but is rarely at the same place which is an issue for the macro I created. I want to put it far on the right but always at the same spot to be able to start my macro without adding columns in the middle of the datas as I have been doing so far

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    activate

    set othervalues to "other_values"

    set searchRange to range ("A1:Z1")

    set foundColumn to find searchRange what othervalues with match case

    set rowCount to count of rows

    goto reference foundColumn


end tell
```

This codes works properly and selects the term "other_values" wherever it is, knowing it is always in the first row of the file. Now it needs to select the column and duplicate it

I realise I must have done the hardest part but as a newbie in both Excel and Applescript, I can't figure out how to select the entire column

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever has the same issue, here is the answer:

```
##Find Other Values Column

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    activate
    set othervalues to "other_values"
    set searchRange to range ("A1:Z1")
    set foundColumn to find searchRange what othervalues with match case
    goto reference foundColumn

    ##Duplicate Column##

    set addr to get address (column 1 of selection)
    set addr to text 2 thru 2 of addr
    ## e.g range $H:$H"
    set myWantedRange to "$" & addr & ":$" & addr
    set src to range myWantedRange of sheet 1 of workbook "Workbook1"
    set dst to range "$Z:$Z" of sheet 1 of workbook "Workbook1"

    copy range src destination dst
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach which doesn't involve any selections:

Begins with the used range then gets the 'other_values' column. Builds the range for column Z and then copies the 'other_values' column there.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell worksheet 1 of workbook 1
        
        set cour to columns of used range
        set ic to columns of used range whose value of cell 1 is "other_values" -- gets target column
        
        set fri to first row index of last cell of last item of cour -- gets bottom row number
        set zsa to intersect range1 entire row of range ("A1:A" & fri as text) range2 range ("Z1:Z" & fri as text) -- assembles destination range
        copy range ic destination zsa
    end tell
end tell
```